# COUNTIF関数で=と一致するセルの数を求めたい

Tags: excel

どうも`=`が制御文字と認識されるらしく
`=Countif(範囲,"=")`では認識しません。

ワイルドカード文字(`*`)を`~`でエスケープする情報をネットで見つけたので
例）`=Countif(範囲,"*~**")`

これに倣い`=Countif(範囲,"~=")`を試してみましたが出来ませんでした。
ご助力お願いします。

【環境】
Windows10 (1909)
Office 2016

Comment: 「=Countif(範囲,"=")では認識しません」という現象が起きた時の範囲に含まれている各セルの内容を教えてください。
　セルに何が入っているのか判らないのでは、認識されるべきなのかどうかを判断できませんから。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もっと簡単に `=COUNTIF(範囲,"==")` で一致してくれました。（最初試したときはうまく行かなったと思ったんだけどなぁ…）

---

セルに `=COUNT(IF(範囲="=",1))` と入力してから Ctrl+Shift+Enter でどうでしょうか？

配列数式と呼ばれる機能で、数式を配列として処理するので、各セル毎に `= "="` の評価をしてからカウントしてくれます。数式バーには `{=COUNT(IF(範囲="=",1))}` と表示されます。

---

質問文に対する補足

[COUNTIF関数](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/countif-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)は単純一致するセルを数えるだけでなく、検索条件を満たすセルを数える機能も持ちます。検索条件として `=` と指定した場合、数式として判断され `=""` つまり空と一致するセルを数える動作をします。これが質問文で言及されている「認識しません」の意味です。
`~`で打ち消すことができるのは`?`と`*`のワイルドカード文字だけのようです。

Comment: `=COUNTIF(範囲,"==") `で一致しました。空ブックでうまく行ったのに適用したいファイルでうまく行かないトラブルに見舞われましたが全角と半角の不一致が起きていただけでした・・・。